# c# object detection

Tags: c#, image, object, detection, aforge

http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/3315/yenidusuk100003.jpg

**how can i find coordinates of the rectangle in the above picture  using Aforge or any c# library?**

*i have tried. but it's too slow.*

And these position and size of the rectangles are static.

i found the following code. but can not get any result.

```
Bitmap image = sourceImage; //(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);


     BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

     blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
     blobCounter.MinHeight = 1;
     blobCounter.MinWidth = 1;

     blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
     Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();


     SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

     foreach (var blob in blobs)
     {
         List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
         List<IntPoint> cornerPoints;


         if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out cornerPoints))
         {

             if (shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(cornerPoints) == PolygonSubType.Rectangle)
             {

                 List<System.Drawing.Point> Points = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();
                 foreach (var point in cornerPoints)
                 {
                     Points.Add(new System.Drawing.Point(point.X, point.Y));
                 }

                 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                 g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Red, 5.0f), Points.ToArray());

                 image.Save("result.png");
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: What is slow? Your hoping to find four pixels of an image so it sounds inheritently "slow".. If its only for that picture that you need it why not just open mspaint?

Comment: i need exactly the coordinates

Comment: You can do that with mspaint? top left is 58,8 for example